# How do I get all the values of a element from a jsonobject containing multiple arrays?

Tags: android, arrays, json

Hi I am new to using json files and am totally lost. I have a jsonobject containing multiple arrays and need to get the value of key title from all the arrays to populate a listview. I know how to get the values of a single array by name but don't have a clue where to start on getting values from more than one array without using the name. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have been over tons of examples and none seem to fit what I am trying to do.

My json code

```
    {
"1":[{"gameid":"1","title":"This Game","more stuff":"stuff 1"}]
,"2":[{"gameid":"2","title":"That Game","more stuff":"stuff 2"}]
,"3":[{"gameid":"3","title":"Another game","more stuff":"stuff 3"}]
}
```

I think I need to loop through each array get the value I want then move to the next array. I need to do this without knowing the array name since I will not know how many arrays will be in the object. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a json library like Gson? https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all the object nodes in your json without knowing their names. An Example below using jackson:

```
public class Resolver {

    public static List<String> getTitles(final String jsonString) 
        throws IOException {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = json.fields();

        while(fields.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fields.next();
            System.out.println("|" + entry.getKey() + "| = entry.getKey()");
            System.out.println("|" + entry.getValue() + "| = entry.getValue()");
            result.add(entry.getValue().findPath("title").asText());
            System.out.println("****************************");
        }

        return result;
    } 
}
```

Test class:

```
public class ResolverTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetTitles() throws Exception {
        final String jsonString = "{"
        + "\"1\":[{\"gameid\":\"1\",\"title\":\"This Game\",\"more stuff\":\"stuff 1\"}]"
        + ",\"2\":[{\"gameid\":\"2\",\"title\":\"That Game\",\"more stuff\":\"stuff 2\"}]"
        + ",\"3\":[{\"gameid\":\"3\",\"title\":\"Another game\",\"more stuff\":\"stuff 3\"}]"
        + "}";


        List<String> ids = Resolver.getTitles(jsonString);
        System.out.println("|" + ids + "| = ids");

        Assert.assertEquals(3, ids.size());
    }
}
```

Output:

|1| = entry.getKey()
|[{"gameid":"1","title":"This Game","more stuff":"stuff 1"}]| = entry.getValue()

---

|2| = entry.getKey()
|[{"gameid":"2","title":"That Game","more stuff":"stuff 2"}]| = entry.getValue()

---

|3| = entry.getKey()
|[{"gameid":"3","title":"Another game","more stuff":"stuff 3"}]| = entry.getValue()

---

|[This Game, That Game, Another game]| = ids

Comment: I ended up doing something different and solved my problem with PHP on the server but am marking this as the best answer since you gave me some example code. Using GSON or Jackson looks like the way to go when working with json files and I will be using them in future projects. thanks again for the replies.